# The correct NSPredicate format for one-to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, one-to-many, nspredicate

I have a managed object model A and B with one-to-many relationship.

For this particular task, I want to retrieve all A objects which has a relation to B with a property matches to "string".

I had tried `@"ALL bObjects.bProperty MATCHES 'string'"`, and it caused an objc_exception_throw in:

```m
[NSSQLGenerator generateSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:]
```

What seems to be the problem ?

Anybody can advise me on the correct predicate format ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001792-249799) you can't use the `MATCHES` operator when fetching from Core Data SQL stores.

> The `matches` operator uses `regex`, so is not supported by Core Data’s SQL store— although it does work with in-memory filtering.

As for the remaining parts of your predicate, it would currently only return `A` objects where the entire set of `bObjects` has a `bProperty` that matches your input string.

If what you want is to return any `A` objects that have any object within the `bObjects` set that match you would want to use the `ANY` operator modifier.

```
ANY bObjects.bProperty LIKE[cd] 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out that limitations, yes as much as I want to believe the documentation, I tried MATCHES for SQLite fetch request, and it does work, though for safety I changed it into LIKE.

The only thing that doesn't work is if I'm using this predicate on Core Data using SQLite storage with a fetch request on a related object (to-many in this case), not using matches.

Right now, I'm not using fetch query based on relationship, it's too risky, and I still don't know what's the mistake, I had posted this on devforums.apple.com, nobody still answer it though.